# Script reading from STDIN

Tags: php, stdin

I have a php script that reads text files. I use `fgetc()` to get every character one by one. I open file to read from with `fopen()`,and then I use file descriptor returned from `fopen()` as a first argument to `fgetc()`. I tried to do the same thing with reading from `STDIN`. I wanted to run the script in a terminal, give it the whole text (that was in a text file before) and press enter. I thought that the script would read it and will run as if it read from a text file, but it doesn't work. It only works when a type every single character alone and press enter after it. Why is that? Is there a possibility to make the script behave the way I wanted? That I can give it the whole text to the terminal at once? Should I use different functions or something?

```
$inputFile = fopen($path, "w");
while(($char = fgetc($inputFile)) !== false){
    dosomething();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace `$inputFile` in `fgetc()`with `STDIN`.

Comment: and where is the code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, thought I expressed myself clearly, I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php, second comment

> Note, without the stream_set_blocking() call, fgetcsv() hangs on STDIN, awaiting input from the user, which isn't useful as we're looking for a piped file. If it isn't here already, it isn't going to be.

```
<?php
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);
$csv_ar = fgetcsv(STDIN);
```

I think it's the same for `fgetc`. After all it

> string fgetc ( resource $handle ) Gets a **character** from the given file pointer.

Emphasis mine.
See  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php
    ...